# LeetCode 804. Unique Morse Code Words, reference binding to null pointer of type 'value_type'

Tags: algorithm

```
class Solution {
public:
    string morseAlpabet[26] = { ".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..", ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---", ".--.", "--.-", ".-.", "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--.." };
    int uniqueMorseRepresentations(vector<string>& words) {
    string words2morse[200] = {};
    int wordsNum = 0;
    //word count
    while (int(words[wordsNum].length())!=0) {
        wordsNum += 1;
    }
    //count word length
    int wordLength = 0;
    string morseCodesThisWord = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < wordsNum; i++) {
        wordLength = words[i].length();
        morseCodesThisWord = "";
        for (int j = 0; j < wordLength; j++) {
            int wordLetterOrder = int(words[i][j] - 'a');
            morseCodesThisWord += morseAlpabet[wordLetterOrder];
        }
        words2morse[i] = morseCodesThisWord;
    }
    set<string> morseKind(words2morse, words2morse + wordsNum);
    return int(morseKind.size());
    }
};
```

This code works well when I run it in visual studio 2017 localy, but when I run it  in Leetcode it raise an Runtimr error as "reference binding to null pointer of type 'value_type'",I don't know if it can be accepted, but I have to handle this error first.Does anyone can help? please!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found it finally :(
`words[wordsNum]`is a wrong way, we should use `words.size()` directly.After changing the code like this. It was accepted.

```
class Solution {
public:
    string morseAlpabet[26] = { ".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..", ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---", ".--.", "--.-", ".-.", "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--.." };
    int uniqueMorseRepresentations(vector<string>& words) {
        string words2morse[200] = {};
        //count word length
        int wordLength = 0;
        string morseCodesThisWord = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
            wordLength = words[i].length();
            morseCodesThisWord = "";
            for (int j = 0; j < wordLength; j++) {
                int wordLetterOrder = int(words[i][j] - 'a');
                morseCodesThisWord += morseAlpabet[wordLetterOrder];
            }
            words2morse[i] = morseCodesThisWord;
        }
        set<string> morseKind(words2morse, words2morse +  words.size());
        return int(morseKind.size()); 
    }
};
```